# MVC3 zip files and download

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, zip, download

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  I am needing to zip a subset of files in a folder and save to the user's Harddrive.  I already am downloading individual files, but need to have "Download Multiple Files" functionality.  Below is the code for individual files.

```
fileName = fileName.Contains("Artifact") ? 
   fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("Artifact:") + 11).Trim() : 
   fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("Working Document:") + 19).Trim();
var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(GetDirectoryPath(boeId, proposalId, aType) + "\\" + fileName);
return File(fs, "application/zip", fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using System.IO.Packaging.  Attached is the url I used for example code 
[System.IO.Packaging example.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options. They are most probably the most popular for c#. GZip is a part of the .net framework.  ISharpZipLib is another great option, that i have used with a lot of sucess.

[GZip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

[ISharpzip](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)

Comment: @Ryand...I don't think Gzip is going to work.  I need to download standard .zip files so the user can just double click that fille to extract